# Commutativity of two sums

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_{ij} \ge 0$ be real numbers, how can we show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}$$

also, why do the $a_{ij}$ have to be non negative ?

Comment: I think this is related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ma_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}$$

So the limit exists on LHS if and only if the limit exists on RHS.

If so then they are the same.

If the $a_{ij}$ are nonnegative then - denoting both (equal) sides as  $s_n$ - the sequence $(s_n)_n$ is increasing and this ensures the existence of the limit (if $+\infty$ is also accepted as limit).

If it is not demanded that the $a_{ij}$ are nonnegative then it might be that $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n$ does not exist.